# ASP.NET: Authorize MVC Action with Bearer Token through AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

this is my first post in SO.

I have a single ASP.NET project, it uses Web API in the back end with bearer token authentication which works perfectly using PostMan. Though, I am struggling in the front end (SPA only using jQuery).

What I want, is to be able to call an MVC Action with the Bearer Token attached to it and succesfully authenticate with Identity User so I can have the next benefits:

-Call MVC Action with [Authorize] attribute. I want to handle authentication and authorization in the server rather that doing it using JavaScript. It will also handle Role Authorization.

-Call an MVC Action that would instantiate an Api Controller and call an Api Action, create a ViewModel from the Api Actions response and generate a partial view. This will avoid jQuery from inserting data into the DOM, since the MVC action will return the Partial View with the data.

-Use Razor Partial Views to it's fullest with models passed from the MVC Action. It will also allow me to use conditions on the Partial View so I can show extra content if a User with Administrator Role requests it for example.

I've read that MVC should authenticate using Cookie Authentication, how I would achieve this? My Log In Form requests the Bearer Token directly through AJAX on submit. Thanks in advance.

GitHub with Source Code: https://github.com/RolandoMalena/jogtrackr/tree/master/jogtrackr/Web/JogTrackr

JavaScript function to get HTML from a given End Point:

```
function getHTML(endPoint, callback) {
$.ajax({
    //headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') },
    datatype: "text/html",
    type: "GET",
    url: endPoint,
    cache: true,
    success: function (result) {
        callback(result);
    }
});
```

An example call to the above function:

```
getHTML('/Entries/GetWeeklyReport', function (result) {
                content.find("#loading").before(result);
            });
```

Example MVC Controller, notice that I GetUserId() returns null:

```
public PartialViewResult GetWeeklyReport()
    {
        //this returns null
        var temp = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        return PartialView("_WeeklyReport");
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the controller and the javascript where the request is done.

Comment: @LazerBass Done, also added the GitHub link.